# C++ cin: don't show the newline

Tags: c++, input

If I get some value by using `getline( cin, myStr );` a newline is printed after the information the user entered - logically as he pressed enter:

```
Please enter something: ABC <enter => \n>
This text is printed out by the program and should be in the same line as before
```

- How to keep the newline after user input away?

I'm using MSVC 2010 and build a simple console app using `iostream` and `string` as main libraries.

Answer (score 1):

You can't - the newline processing isn't controlled by the C++ program. What you can do is use the [Windows console APIs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx) to reposition the cursor after the input. Or use those APIs to write your own version of getline().

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this using just standard C++. I'd recommend looking at [PDCurses](http://pdcurses.sourceforge.net/), which is a Windows-compatible replacement of [NCurses](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/).