# Modify cin to also return the newlines

Tags: c++

I know about `getline()` but it would be nice if `cin` could return `\n` when encountered.

Any way for achieving this (or similar)?

edit (example):

```
string s;
while(cin>>s){
    if(s == "\n")
        cout<<"newline! ";
    else
        cout<<s<<" ";
}
```

input file txt:

```
hola,          em dic pere
caram, jo    també    .
```

the end result shoud be like:

```
hola, em dic pere newline! caram, jo també .
```

Comment: IOstreams skip any whitespace character by design when used for formatted IO. Use unformatted IO (aka `std::cin.get()`, `std::cin.read()`, `std::cout.put()`, `std::cout.write()`) if you don't want that behaviour.

Comment: Which `getline` are you referring to?

Comment: @CharlesBailey this one http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/getline/

Comment: @inuart: In that case, why not just append `\n` to the `std::string`. It's probably the simplest thing to do.

Comment: @CharlesBailey the thing is that I don't know where `\n` will be in an input file with lines with space-separated numbers, to do an operation to every number in the line. thank you for your time

Comment: @Inuart: Perhaps you should clarify your question because I don't understand what you are asking. `getline` only stops on reading on `\n` or the end of input so if you're using `getline` the spaces will be embedded in the read string and the read will have been terminated with `\n` other than possibly the last line read.

Comment: OK, I still don't understand what you are trying to achieve. `>>` reads a whitespace separated string so the read string will never contain only whitespace. Are you trying to read lines or read terminated strings and determine what the separator is on each occasion?

Comment: @CharlesBailey just read individual words and do some extra work every newline

Comment: @Inuart: Then you can just use `.peek()` after reading each word to see what character (if any) terminated the word. Of course you might be confused by ` ` (space) then `\n` so you might want to repeatedly `.get()` and `.peek()` until you encounter the next non-whitespace character.

Comment: ok I have a solution now, will post it tomorrow (not enough reputation)

Comment: It cant be done, use `getch()`.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2649112/c-cin-dont-show-the-newline

Comment: @MatthWhiz ok I get it, I was searching for a nice workaround, thanks for pointing this out though

Comment: @Inuart, you admit that getline solves the problem, so why do you want to change the behaviour of `cin >>`? I think you should forget about `cin >>` and `getline(cin,...)` and simply tell us what you are trying to do in your algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A modification of @Dietmar's answer should do the trick:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); )
{
    std::istringstream iss(line);
    for (std::string word; iss >> word; ) { std::cout << word << " "; }
    if (in.eof()) { std::cout << "newline! "; }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

If you are reading individual lines, you **know** that there is a newline after each read line. Well, except for the last line in the file which doesn't have to be delimited by a newline character for the read to be successful but you can detect if there is newline by checking `eof()`: if `std::getline()` was successful but `eof()` is set, the last line didn't contain a newline. Obviously, this requires the use of the `std::string` version of `std::getline()`:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); )
{
    std::cout << line << (in.eof()? "": "\n");
}
```

This should write the stream to `std::cout` as it was read.

The question asked for the data to be output but with newlines converted to say "newline!". You can achieve this with:

```
for (std::string line; std::getline(in, line); )
{
    std::cout << line << (in.eof()? "": "newline! ");
}
```

If you don't care about the stream being split into line but actually just want to get the entire file (including all newlines), you can just read the stream into a `std::string`:

```
std::string file((std::istreambuf_iterator<char>(in)),
                 std::istreambuf_iterator<char>());
```

Note, however, that this exact approach is probably fairly slow (although I **know** that it can be made fast). If you know that the file doesn't contain a certain character, you can also use `std::getline()` to read the entire file into a `std::string`:

```
std::getline(in, file, 0);
```

The above code assumes that your file doesn't contain any null characters.

Comment: Thank you! I was searching for a simpler way though

Comment: I think this is a very simple solution! What simpler solution do you want, @Inuart?

Comment: I edited this answer a little to solve the exact problem in the question - to convert `\n` to `newline!`.

Comment: ok sorry, this was really simple and mostly solved what I asked

Answer (score 0):

Just for the record, I ended up using this (I wanted to post it 11h ago)

```
string s0, s1;
while(getline(cin,s0)){
    istringstream is(s0);
    while(is>>s1){
        cout<<s1<<" ";
    }
    cout<<"newline! ";
}
```

Comment: This will print a spurious `"newline! "` if your input file doesn't actually end in a newline.